# 1950s, UK-Soviet sporting event

Tags: sports

I'm trying to find some details about an event that my father has a vague memory of. I'm sorry this is quite vague.

It was an international event happening in about the 1950s.
It was a sporting competition between Britain and the Soviet Union taking place in England. During the event one of the Soviet athletes was arrested for shoplifting. The minor diplomatic incident resulted in the whole of the Soviet team being recalled to Russia and the event cancelled.

Does anyone know what event this may be referring to, or when it may have taken place?

Thank you for your help

James

Comment: A quick google search reveals [this](https://news.google.com/newspapers?id=u7sbAAAAIBAJ&sjid=PE4EAAAAIBAJ&pg=7218%2C3301929) from August 27, 1956. Nina Pomorevna vanished after shoplifting 5 pastel beret's.

Comment: Searching futher on Nina, I found [her Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nina_Ponomaryova), which does not mention the incident (perhaps it needs to be added), and [this nearly incoherent description](https://hfryan.wordpress.com/tag/nina-ponomareva/) of the incident. So this does appear to be what you were thinking of. It mentioned that the canceled event was being held at [White City](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_City_Stadium), but not much more factual info in there that I trust.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed. I think this is an interesting story in relation to UK-Soviet relations. I found it difficult to find any information about so thank you for the links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That was UK vs. USSR athletics competition similar to ones [USA vs. USSR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USA%E2%80%93USSR_Track_and_Field_Dual_Meet_Series). Not much info about it, as it was obviously cancelled.

This is [interview with Nina Ponomaryova](http://www.sport-express.ru/fridays/reviews/835630/) published on 6th February, 2015 by Russian magazine "Sport-Express".

When asked about that incident she said the following:

> *– Вас обвиняли в попытке кражи дамской шляпки?*
>   – Не шляпки – ободка с перьями. Ценой 5 фунтов. Это случилось на матче сборных СССР и Великобритании – через два года после скандала с Куцем. Только теперь в роли жертвы оказалась я. В выходной привезли в торговый центр. Я выбрала ободок, положила в сумку, расплатилась. И побежала искать подружку, которая покупала платье.
>   Неожиданно приглашают в комнату. Думала, примерочная, подружка там. Но это совсем другое помещение. Помню, посмотрела на часы – 10.22. Через минуту открывается запасная дверь, входит молодой человек, по-русски произносит: "Я переводчик". Отвечаю: "Еще никто не спрашивал, кто я, откуда. Может, я француженка? Или немка?" Окончательно убедилась, что это провокация, когда к обеду принесли местную газету. С шапкой на первой полосе: "Пономарева в Мельбурн не едет! Советская команда теряет золотую медаль!"
>   *– Однако.*
>   – Вызвали представителя посольства. Начали разбираться, тщетно просили снять кассу, чтобы найти чек, который я не взяла… А в Великобритании закон: любой спорный вопрос решается в суде. Но когда доложили в Москву Хрущеву, тот отрезал: "Никаких судов! Нашему человеку там не место!" Когда на следующий день туда не явилась, на меня автоматически наложили арест. После чего укрыться могла только в нашем посольстве.
>   *– Что вы там делали?*
>   – Рыдала целыми днями. Чесалась на нервной почве. Потом стала седеть. В 27 лет! С тех пор ношу короткую стрижку. Вы не представляете, что я пережила… Квартиру и наше посольство отделяла дорога. Так под окнами ночью дежурили репортеры, зеваки, расставили палатки. Следили, чтоб я не проскочила.
>   *– Чем дело кончилось?*
>   – В суд пойти все-таки пришлось. С адвокатом, бумагами. Там выяснилось – мало того, что я ни в чем не виновата, так еще меня на три шиллинга надули. Вопрос закрылся. Но я попросила, чтоб домой отправили пароходом.
>   *– Почему?*
>   – Боялась – вдруг с рейса снимут или еще какую-нибудь пакость придумают? Лучше по морю, тогда из Лондона в Ленинград ходил корабль. На нем вернулась. И почти сразу – в Мельбурн. Там в аэропорту встречала толпа, со всех сторон неслось: "Нина! Нина!" Я расплакалась. Понимала, что люди меня ждали и думали: если прилечу на Олимпиаду – значит, точно ни в чем не виновата.

Translating into English this roughly means: that was not hat but some "rim with feathers" cost about 5 pounds; that happened during the match of SU vs. UK, two years after the incident with [Kuts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vladimir_Kuts) (probably she made mistake here, as car accident with Kuts took place in Melbourne - later she mentions that all happened a little before Melbourne Olympics 1956); she also says that she paid but didn't take cheque and returned to find her friend; that was provocation etc.etc. She also says that her coming to court was prohibited by Khrushev himself. But later that was resettled, so she finally appeared before the court and was absolved.

Comment: Interesting. The weird link I dug up indicated a possibility that she did what usually passed for "paying" in the Soviet Union, but didn't realize in a capitalist country actual paper money had to change hands. Any support for that in the interview?

Comment: @T.E.D. I see nothing of that kind. Following your link, they discuss some order-based shopping, which I'm not aware of. My best guess it belongs to the Soviet "closed distribution" system. But she must know how common shops work too. Also mentioning GUM is pointless anyway, as closed section in GUM was only for elite.